# Prove that $L(Im(L))=Im(L)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$. Let $L:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear mapping such that $Im(L)\cap Ker(L)=\{0\}$
Show that $L(Im(L))=Im(L)$

I know how to prove the coverse of the statement but I have a little problem on proving this. The following steps are what I had tried:

Let $$x\in Im(L)\cap Ker(L)$$
$$x\in Im(L) \text{ and } x\in Ker(L)$$
$$\exists a\in V s.t. L(a)=x \text{ and } L(x)=0$$
From the condition given, I can get
$$L(a)=L(x)=0$$
But how to prove that $a=x$ since I am not sure that this linear mapping is injective or not.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, but I couldn't follow your approach. You have to show $L(\text{Im}(L))=\text{Im}(L)$: Since the inclusion $L(\text{Im}(L))\subset L(V)\equiv\text{Im}(L)$ holds by definition, this means that you have to show that any $x\in\text{Im}(L)$ can be written as $x = L(y)$ with $y$ not only in $V$ (the existence of such a $y$ would just be the definition of $\text{Im}(L)$) but with $y\in\text{Im}(L)$ again. In other words, you have to show that $L|_{\text{Im}(L)}: \text{Im}(L)\to\text{Im}(L)$ is surjective. Now remember that for any homomorphism $f: W\to W$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $W$, injectivity and surjectivity are equivalent, and try to apply this to $W := \text{Im}(L)$ and $f := L|_{\text{Im}(L)}$.

Comment: Can you explain in simpler way? since the endomorphisms you said is beyond what I know

Comment: Dear Alan, I changed the wording - is it clearer now?

Comment: Hmm sorry the properties of homomorphism is also beyond what I have learnt.